# Keras seeding ImageDataGenerator versus Sequence

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, data-generation

I'm currently using `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory`. For example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20,
                                    width_shift_range=0.1,
                                    height_shift_range=0.1,
                                    shear_range=0.2, 
                                    zoom_range=0.2, 
                                    fill_mode='nearest', 
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    rescale=1/255.0, 
                                    preprocessing_function=preprocessing_function, 
                                    data_format='channels_last')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=env.channel_dirs['train'],
    target_size=(train_size, train_size),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    interpolation='bilinear',
    seed=42)
```

I found that even when setting a seed in both numpy and TensorFlow, the batch order is not static so I don't get reproducible results. I saw [this post](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) that recommends using a keras [Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence). However, it only has a small example for this.

Is it possible to make ImageDataGenerator batch order reproducible? Alternatively, does anyone have an example they could share of how I could use `Sequence` but retain the `flow_from_directory` along with using `ImageDataGenerator`'s augmentation options? If an example is asking too much, summarizing how to go about this would also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [nice-script](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly), by which you can control the inner process too. It means, you can define your own way of generating data in each iteration, along with flowing data from directory.

Comment: Thanks this has a lot of what I've been looking for. I think I can create the flow_from_directory from here. Is there any way to make use of ImageDataGenerator's augmentations without having to rewrite them?

Comment: You can add that function from keras code, to your script. This is dirty way of doing it, but it is one option.